# Unknown type name

Tags: c++, struct, объявление

Если создать два типа структур `A` и `B`:

```
typedef struct A {
    A(B b) {};
} A;

typedef struct B {
    B(A a) {};
} B;
```

То для `A` появится ошибка:

> Unknown type name 'B'

так как он объявлен позднее. Если объявить `B` раньше `A`, то ошибка появится у конструктора `B`. Есть ли что-то вроде прототипов функций, но для пользовательских типов и классов?

Comment: Можете пояснить, зачем вам в C++ определять typedef структуры с именем структуры, когда и так вы можете обращаться по имени структуры без typedef?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать ссылки и указатели на типы, которые будут определены позднее, используя forward declaration:

```
struct B;

struct A {
    A(B& b) {};
};

struct B {
    B(A& a) {};
};
```

Но использовать просто тип в вызове нельзя - ведь, например, размер этого типа компилятору до полного объявления неизвестен.

P.S. Конструкция `typedef struct A { ... } A;` в C++ не нужна.

Comment: А теперь попробуйте создать объект одной из этих структур.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `struct A {
    A(){}
    A(B& b) {};
};

struct B {
    B(A& a) {};
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    B b(a);
}`
 Или вы считаете, что в ответах надо приводить полный текст программы, а не поясняющие фрагменты?

Comment: @ Harry  Я вас спрашиваю про исходный вопрос, а не про ваш собственный выдуманный класс.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Софистика. Если не демагогия. Мне некогда заниматься препирательством с пустыми придирками. У вас есть время - вперед, а я "не интеллигент, у меня профессия есть" (с) :)

Comment: На самом с чисто декларативной точки зрения нет формальной необходимости переходить к ссылкам: С++ прекрасно разрешает использовать незавершенные (incomplete) типы в *объявлениях* функций (в объявлениях параметров и типе возврата). Эти типы должны стать завершенными (complete) только к моменту *определения* этих функций. Таким образом в данном случае можно сохранить передачу по значению, надо лишь вынести определение `A::A` за пределы определения класса `A` и поместить его после определения класса `B`.

Answer (score 0):

В C++ не имеет большого смысла вводить алиасы имен для структур таким образом, так как в C++ вы к структуре можете обращаться по ее имени без ключевого слова `struct`. Это имеет смысл делать только в C, но в C нет конструкторов структур. Поэтому не понятно, чего вы стремитесь достичь.

Но даже если вы напишите так, чтобы код компилировался, как например,

```
typedef struct A A;
typedef struct B B;

struct A 
{
    A( B );
};

struct B 
{
    B( A );
};

A::A( B ) { /*...*/ }
B::B( A ) { /(...(/ }
```

Тем не менее вы не сможете создать ни один объект данных структур, так как у вас циклическая зависимость вызовов конструкторов.

Поэтому чтобы код имел смысл, вам необходимо по крайней мере в одну из структур добавить дополнительный конструктор, который не зависит от объекта другого класса, чтобы избежать циклической зависимости вызовов конструкторов.